# Yii urlManager route with query string

Tags: php, query-string, url-routing, yii

This is about setting **WebRoot/protected/config/main.php** **urlManager** on **Yii Framework**.

I want a few predefined url like `/About` `/Contact` or some other custom special page like `/LatestUpdates` or `/HTCDesire`

I can do 'Contact'=>'site/contact' to map /Contact to /site/contact

How can I 'hard code' query string to the route?

I try:

```
'About'=>'site/page?view=about'
'LatestUpdates'=>'update/view?id=65'
'HTCDesire'=>'product/view?id=33'
```

but not working, 404 not found because it expect the right side should be route in format *controller/action*.

I try:

```
'LatestUpdates'=>'update/view/id/65'
```

I can browse to `/LatestUpdates` but the anchor link still shows `/update/view/id/65`

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me (except I substituted your values in, so maybe I broke it...):

```
'LatestUpdates'=>array('update/view','defaultParams'=>array('id'=>'65')),
```

More about this [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule#defaultParams).

Cheers!

Comment: +1 for pointing out something very useful that I had no idea about :)

Comment: Yeah, great. Its working and you also give the right example. Very ~similar with ASP.NET MVC on most of the MVC way including setting @soap in doccomment for web service ~ setting Attribute on top of the function name in ASP.NET MVC. I don't think so this routing process and the default params are the ~same. Yii ~ ASP.NET MVC. Thanks.